# My netbeans project can't run or debug

Tags: java, netbeans

Target "debug" does not exist in the project "Project Name". 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
Above message come under output window after run or debug button play.how I solve this matter and 
run the project

Comment: Right click the project and clean and build or copy project file to new project

Comment: K buddy tnx for your contribution and I will try it..

Comment: Known issue of NB 8.0.  No one seems to know why, best bet seems to be restart NB: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242261

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ohhh,try to delete the build.xml file and rename project name.then run the project.It will be work.

Comment: I couldn't run or rebuild my Java project (restarting NetBeans 8.0.1 didn't help), but after removing `build.xml` and restarting NetBeans, I could.

Comment: Also, check /nbproject folder and see the libraries path from build-impl.xml. My problem is that I had to change it a bit when moving the application on production. Search for line <replacestring from=" " to="%20"/> and see below <globmapper from="*" to="libraries/*"/>. On server the "to" element pointed on other location so my local version could not find it.